# Group action($G$-action) induces, $G/N$ action on the same set. And in normal groups $n_0nn_0^{-1}=n$

Tags: group-theory, group-actions

Let $N$ be a normal subgroup of $G$. $G$ acts from right on the set
$$R_m=\left\{\rho: N \longrightarrow G L_m(F)\;|\;\quad \rho \text{ is a group homo.}\right\}$$
as follows: for $g \in G,(\rho \cdot g)(n):=\rho\left(g n g^{-1}\right)$ for every $n \in N$.

**Question:** This action, also defines an action of $G / N$ on $R_m$.

**Attempt:**

Now I want to use universal property of quotient groups and I want to use the following version of an $G$ action on $R_m$.
$$a:G\to Aut(R_m)$$

and

$$
\require{AMScd} \begin{CD} G @>\pi_N>> G/N\\ @.     {_{\rlap{\ a}}\style{display: inline-block; transform: rotate(31deg)}{{\xrightarrow[\rule{4em}{0em}]{}}}} @VV\exists ! \bar aV\\  @. Aut(R_m) \end{CD}$$

To be able to say existence of such $\bar a$ group homomorphism, I need to show $ker(a)\supset N$

So the group homomorphism $a$ is actually defined as:

$$a(g):R_m\to R_m\\ \rho\mapsto \rho\cdot g$$

So since the identity element of $Aut(R_m)$ is identity. I need to show for given $n_0\in N$ the map $a(n_0)=Id_{R_m}$

So equivalently need to show for every $n\in N$:
$$a(n_0)(\rho)(n)=(\rho\cdot n_0)(n)=\rho(n_0nn_0^{-1})\\=\rho(n)$$

But I cannot recall if $N\subset G$ is a normal, these conjugates commute? Do we have $n,n_0\in N$ , $n_0nn_0^{-1}=n$?

Comment: You just need to check that whether the action of $G$ is constant on $N$.

Comment: yes i understood that but in above way how to show the kernel N inclusion

Comment: Are you sure you have the definition of $R_m$ right? Do you want the maps $\rho$ to be group homomorphisms?

Comment: @DerekHolt  I ask the lecturer but waiting the response. I highly think they should be group homomorphism since we are generally dealing with group representations

Comment: even if assuming they are group homo, $\rho(n_0nn_0^{-1})=\rho(n)$ is not obvious since invertible matrices doesnot have to commute...

Comment: $n_0nn_0^{-1}=n$ if and only if $n$ and $n_0$ commute, which is trivially not necessarily true (unless you have more information on $N$ than just "$N$ is normal in $G$". We have that $n\in N$ commutes with each of its $N$-conjugates if and only if it belongs to an abelian normal subgroup of $N$; see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3760884/742).

Comment: There is a standard notion of equivalent representations in Representation Theory. If you defined $R_m$ as the set of equivalence classes of representations of $N$ of degree $m$ over the field $F$, then you would get an induced action of $G/N$ on $R_m$, because the action of $N$ maps a representation to an equivalent poe.